# Cannot scrape email data but can scrape name using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.asta.org/membership/directory-search-details?memId=900312276"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

data = []
for item in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "asta-member"}):
    name = item.find("h4", {"class": "asta-member__name"}).text
    data.append([name])
for item in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "asta-member_title"}):
    email = item.find("div")[2].text
    data.append([email])

with open("contacts.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["name", "email"])
    writer.writerows(data)
```

[inspect data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O5Cg.png)

script scrapes the name data as its in its own class, but cannot understand what class/other directory to put in script to scrape email

I have tried everything I can think of

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion:

Since the `div` for email has no `class` or `id` you can use the `.contents` method in beautiful soup. This method lists all the tag contents.

In this case, we will get all the content on `"class": "asta-member"` since the email div is under it and extract the email text.

### Code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.asta.org/membership/directory-search-details?memId=900312276"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
soup
data = []

for item in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "asta-member"}):
    name = item.find("h4", {"class": "asta-member__name"}).text
    data.append(name)
    #Code changes here
for item in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "asta-member"}):
    email = item.contents[7].text.strip()
    data.append(email)

with open("contacts.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["name", "email"])
    writer.writerow(data)

#reading the CSV file  
df = pd.read_csv('/content/contacts.csv')
df
```

### Output:

[image]

### Reference:

https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#contents-and-children